# Rspec Test Passing in wrong var?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I wrote a test for a controller and recently had to refactor the new method a bit. My old test failed and I can't figure out why it isn't passing. I am new to testing so my understanding is limited.

My method below basically receives a `slug_text` param. From the `slug_text`, we can get the id of the place and its type (polymorphic). Using these values, we can find the record in the DB.

```
def new
  @slug = params[:slug_text]
  place_id = Slug.where(name: @slug).first.sluggable_id.to_i
  place_type = Slug.where(name: @slug).first.sluggable_type.to_s
  @klass = place_type.classify.constantize
  @place = @klass.find(place_id)
end
```

The action seems functional in the view, however, my test keeps failing saying that it `expects 1, but receives 0`.

```
it "sends the query to the correct class" do
  Hotel.should_receive(:find).with(1)
  get :new, place_type: "Hotel", id: 1
end
```

This test should be checking the last two lines of my method and making sure I'm pulling the correct record.

Am I incorrectly passing `place_type` in as a symbol and furthermore, do I have to pass in `:slug_text` or can I start testing any line?

Comment: For starters, from what I can see, you're not sending your sending your `new` action a `slug_text` param. Why are you sending it a `place_type` and an `id`? Your `new` action doesn't do anything with those params. It should be `get :new, :slug_text => "something"`.

Comment: @MrDanA I wasn't sure if I can test specific lines in my method or if I have to start from the very top passing in specific parameters. I figured my test can just test the last two lines above. I'll try what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: No, unfortunately you cannot just target specific lines in your code. You'll have to call the method in its entirety, and then try to test what it is you want to test. So in this case, you'd want to send a `slug_text` that will return a `sluggable_type` of "hotel". You can stub all the calls out, but the best way would be to set up the data so that that was true.